# Como colocar cada box separada lado a lado no HTML

Tags: html, css

Olá, pessoal!

Estou trabalhando no design de um template que quero assim:

[image: Esboço do Templete que quero]

Mas está aparecendo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis o código que estou usando:

```css
.container{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 background: #f2f2f2;
}

.ctnFlex{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.cabecalhoFilho{
font-family: Arial; 
font-size: 20px; 
text-align: center; 
padding: 0.5%; 
color:#009563; 
background: #F5B84E; 
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey; 
width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="ctnFlex">
<div class="cabecalhoFilho">{{Artigo}}</div>
<div class="cabecalhoFilho">{{Parágrafo}}</div>
<div class="cabecalhoFilho">{{Inciso}}</div>
<div class="cabecalhoFilho">{{Alínea}}</div>
</>

<br>
```

Comment: Já consegui, pessoal.
Mudei totalmente o que havia postado e funcionou da forma como eu desejo. Obrigado!

Comment: A conversa ficou extensa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132808/discussion-on-question-by-joao-paulo-shuazter-como-colocar-cada-box-separada-lad) - se alguém quiser ler ou acrescentar algo, queira utilizar o link fornecido. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações, convém ler e entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). A [help] também pode ser util.

Answer (score -3):

Na minha interpretação, isso poderia ser resolvido com o grid e 1 jumbotron no boostrap.

Você coloca 4 colunas assim junto com 1 jumbotron:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
  <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      1 de 4 colunas
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      2 de 4 colunas
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      3 de 4 colunas
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      4 de 4 colunas
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

referencia: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width